# Avoiding audio pops

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot, audio-playback

I'm using Windows 10 IoT Core on RPi 3 and adding voice prompts to my product by playing wav files. Using MediaPlayer to Play the Source gives good enough quality through the 3.5mm audio jack apart from the massive pop at the beginning and end of the sound. Has anyone else had this issue and found any solutions? Or is there a better way to go about it?

Comment: It may just be transients in the audio file - have you confirmed that it doesn't pop on other systems?

Comment: I have 3 wav files. My code plays them fine on the PC. They all pop with the same code at the start and end of each sample on the Raspberry Pi 3. Which leads me to think it's the audio hardware on the Pi turning on and off. Has anyone got the internal audio working under IoT?

Comment: I can back up his statement, I've done a few projects with Win10 IOT and RP2&3 and they both pop each time an audio file starts and stops.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem Bought a USB soundcard that has the 3.5 mm out.
All popping gone. 6$ on Amazon